# Prevent a dock from being resized to the point of disappearing

Tags: python, pyside, pyqtgraph

I am building an application with PySide and pyqtgraph, and am constructing it out of a number of docks (pyqtgraph.dockarea.Dock) in a single DockArea. However I have noticed that when resizing the docks by clicking and dragging on the splitters that separate them, you can easily drag them quite small, to the point where they suddenly disappear. After they are gone they will re-appear if you drag the slider, which is still there, back to create space again.

For example, in the dockarea example that comes with pyqtgraph, if you drag the splitter in the left-hand panel down, eventually the lower left dock disappears. Drag it back up and it reappears. How do I prevent the disappearing process from happening at all? I want all docks to always be visible.

I've looked through the pyqtgraph.dockarea code but can't find the method that controls the resizing behaviour. I've already subclassed Dock in my application so if it's necessary to modify a method that way I can do so easily.

**Update**: This code fixes the problem (see Luke's answer below)

```python
class DockArea(pyqtgraph.dockarea.DockArea):
    def makeContainer(self, typ):
        new = super(DockArea, self).makeContainer(typ)
        new.setChildrenCollapsible(False)
        return new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable collapsing via the QSplitters in the DockArea:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html#setCollapsible

Probably the easiest way to affect all containers is to extend `DockArea.makeContainer()`  (note that HContainer and VContainer are subclasses of QSplitter).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (and thank you for pyqtgraph in the first place!)